# Arbitrage on Libor rate and Swap rate

Tags: interest-rate, investment-strategies, arbitrage

I must be wrong here, but still want to know where I am wrong. I found the data of Libor rate and swap rate from this link: 
http://www.interestrateswapstoday.com/libor-rates.html

At the time, I read

USD 6-month Libor rate: L6 = 2.8858%

USD 12-month Libor rate: L12 = 3.1006%

USD 1-year Swap rate: S1 = 2.828%

Then, I calculate

6-month zero bond: P6 = 1/(1 + L6*0.5) = 0.9857762347093784

12-month zero bond: P12 = 1/(1+ L12) = 0.9699264601757894

If above 1-year swap rate is semi-annually settled (this is what I understood, but did not see official explanations), then one shall have

1 = S1*0.5*P6 + (S1*0.5+1)*P12

But, the right hand side is equal to 0.9975800962814657, strictly less than 1. Does it mean there is slight arbitrage opportunity, or otherwise I misunderstood on the definition of the rates in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A swap is an agreement to swap fixed for float payments. The 1 year swap rate (unfortunately the link does not work anymore) is never based on different tenors of Libor because there is basis risk (they do not move in line and are different interest rates) between the two.

A 1 year swap (most common in the US before [Libor cessation](https://www.jpmorgan.com/solutions/cib/markets/leaving-libor#:%7E:text=end%2DSeptember%202024.-,After%20this%2C%20publication%20would%20cease%20permanently.,which%20it%20will%20cease%20permanently.) is the 3m Libor fixed float swap) is swapping a particular Libor tenor (3m for example) for fixed payments. These swaps are quoted for all sorts of tenors but always reference one particular tenor only.

The value of 12m Libor is entirely unrelated to the swap rate of a 3m Libor swap (or 6m Libor swap etc.).